# autocomplete using local array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The following works:

```
$("#txtAllowSearch").autocomplete(
    { source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"] }
);
```

But the following does not work:

```
var $local_source = '["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]';

$("#txtAllowSearch").autocomplete(
    { source: $local_source }
);
```

I am not good with arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the single-quotes:

```
var $local_source = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];
```

otherwise $local_source is a string not an array.